# Remote Access to Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, remote

I have Ubuntu server and GUI desktop.
I want to access to it from windows using Remote Desktop.
How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up remote desktop on Ubuntu is actually very easy. All you need to do is install [`xrdp`](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp).

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install xrdp
```

Reboot the device, and now you can connect to it via Remote Desktop. If you want to change some settings, the config file is documented [in the manpages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/xrdp.ini.5.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed xrdp and can access using remote desktop.

Comment: Can I change the xrdp port? I mean not default port.

Comment: @AlexLee Yes, you can. In the `GLOBALS` section in the linked manpage, there is an option named port. You can just change that to whatever other port you want to use.

Comment: Okay. I changed it, but when I restart the xrdp service there is error. Which part could I change exactly?

Comment: You haven't specified the error, but I'd suggest [making a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with (1) a link to this question (2) the error message and (3) the section of the config file you messed with